# Spring Integration "No bean named 'toFtpChannel' available"

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I need to upload an image to FTP server. So I've created integration configuration with SessionFactory, MessageHandler, and MessageGateway for uploading files to FTP server:

```
@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class FtpConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        //setup
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(defaultFtpSessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toFtpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        FtpMessageHandler handler = new FtpMessageHandler(ftpSessionFactory());
        handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(""));
        handler.setFileNameGenerator(message -> (String) message.getHeaders().get("filename"));
        return handler;
    }

    //to show you that I've tried both
    /*@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow ftpOutboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("toFtpChannel")
                .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory(), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                        .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                        .fileNameExpression("headers['" + FileHeaders.FILENAME + "']")
                        .remoteDirectory("")
                ).get();
    }*/

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface UploadGateway {

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "toFtpChannel")
        void upload(@Payload byte[] file, @Header("filename") String filename, @Header("path") String path);
    }

}
```

Successfully build an application. And then I'm trying to upload some file:

```
@Autowired
UploadGateway uploadGateway;


@Override
public void uploadImage(byte[] scanBytes, String filename, String path) {
    try {
        uploadGateway.upload(scanBytes, filename, path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("WRONG", e);
    }
}
```

And then it says: **"No bean named 'toFtpChannel' available"**
I've tried nearly every tutorial, what do I do wrong?

dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Request channel should exists actually before you can refer it in your annotation. Declare channel and that issue should be gone

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel toFtpChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

This example creates `DirectChannel` but you can choose [any implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel) according your semantic.

Hope it helps!

Comment: See my answer for more obvious reason of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dosn't look like your application is really Spring Boot: we don't see a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. Exactly this one will kick the proper auto-configuration, including one for Spring Integration.

If you still don't care about Spring Boot there, then you are missing a standard `@EnableIntegration` annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#configuration-enable-integration

Answer (score 0):

@Sergey Prokofiev 's answer solved here, but I want to point out a weird thing.

I had a
`@Gateway(requestChannel = "json.event.deserialize.input")`
And the bean below didn't work:

```java
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel jsonEventDeserializeInput() {
        return MessageChannels.direct("json.event.deserialize.input").get();
    }
```

After I changed the gateway to
`@Gateway(requestChannel = "jsonEventDeserializeInput")`
It did work.

So, even though the documentation says that `id(...)` is `Used as the beanName to register the bean in the application context for this component.`, it didn't find any bean with name equal to the value that I passed to `id(...)`.